# passing data between view controllers using combine framework in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying out combine using swift and UIKit. I have a table view with list of data and while I select a row i need to pass the data to detail page. However the data is missing at times when i click same/different row very fast.

```
class GitHubLinkDetails: UIViewController {


 var githubDetails = PassthroughSubject<GitHubModel,Never>()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getDetails()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


 func getDetails() {
       
 githubDetails
         .sink { [weak self] githubData in
                
                self?.username.text = githubData.builtBy[0].username
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

And in table view didselect method i push to the class GitHubLinkDetails along with data

```
class GitHubListing: UIViewController {

    var viewModel = GitHubListingViewModel()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    @IBOutlet weak var gitHubListingTable: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        

        gitHubListingTable.dataSource = self
        gitHubListingTable.delegate = self
        
        self.gitHubListingTable.register(UINib(nibName: "GitHubListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        viewModel.getGitHubListing()
        
       
        
        viewModel.$trendingGitHubList
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.gitHubListingTable.reloadData()
              
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)

    }



}
extension GitHubListing: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.getListCount()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = gitHubListingTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GitHubListCell
        
        viewModel.$trendingGitHubList
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { gitHubModel in
                if let gitHubModel = gitHubModel {
                    cell.configureCell(with: gitHubModel[indexPath.row])
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let gitHubDetails = GitHubLinkDetails()
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        viewModel.$trendingGitHubList
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { githublist in
                if let githublist = githublist {
                    gitHubDetails.githubDetails.send(githublist[indexPath.row])
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(gitHubDetails, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        75
    }
    
}
```

I would appreciate any help. thank you so much

Comment: Without a [mre], this will likely be impossible to debug

Comment: @jnpdx I am sorry, I have updated my question

Comment: It still cannot be compiled and is not a [mre]